# Applying a function with date conditions to Pandas Groups

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: names, dates, activities, and a charge number that relates to the name and activity. I am trying to determine a 5th column that indicates whether a member has repeated an activity within a 30-day window.For example (charge column left out as irrelevant):

| name | date | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 2022-09-01 | run |
| alice | 2022-09-07 | run |
| bob | 2022-08-01 | run |
| char | 2022-10-02 | swim |
| bob | 2022-08-03 | run |
| char | 2022-10-01 | climb |

I want to add the 'repeated' column for an output:

| name | date | activity | repeated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 2022-09-01 | run | true |
| alice | 2022-09-07 | run | true |
| bob | 2022-08-01 | run | false |
| char | 2022-10-02 | swim | false |
| bob | 2022-10-01 | run | false |
| char | 2022-10-06 | climb | false |
| bob | 2022-10-15 | run | true |

If I distill the df down by name, eg df1 = df[df['name']=='example' then I can get the desired column using the function below:

```
def same_activity(df, x):
    time_start = x['date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=15)
    time_end = x['date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=15)
    events = df.loc[(df['date'] >= time_start) & (df['date'] <= time_end)]['activity'].isin([x['activity']])
    return events.sum() > 1


df1['repeated'] = df1.apply(lambda r : same_activity(df1, r), axis=1)
```

I'm trying to use a groupby method to do the same for all the thousands of names in the dataframe, but cannot figure out the correct syntax and feel like I'm missing something ridiculously simple.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your dataset (as code/text) and the matching expected output for clarity.

Comment: can you explain this bit ? `['activity'].isin([x['activity']])` seems to me all your doing is checking if the activity is equal to itself?

Comment: @Umar.H yes, it's checking if the activity is repeated in the timeframe. I just don't know how to make it work for every name without splitting the dataframe

Comment: The two bob/run are within 30D of each other and should be True, no?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['repeated'] = (df.groupby(['name', 'activity'])['date']
                    .transform(lambda s: s.sort_values().diff()
                                          .le('30D').any())
                 )
```

Output:

```
    name       date activity  repeated
0  alice 2022-09-01      run      True
1  alice 2022-09-07      run      True
2    bob 2022-08-01      run      True
3   char 2022-10-02     swim     False
4    bob 2022-08-03      run      True
5   char 2022-10-01    climb     False
```

Comment: The results in the repeated column need to be on a row basis. I think "transform" is part of what I was forgetting though